# How can I use turbolinks and AngularJS in the project without load angular more than once?

Tags: angularjs, turbolinks

I'm working on a website using AngularJS. I'm trying to add turbolinks but it loads angular more than once.

I call turbolinks.js in the Head tag `<script src="/scripts/turbolinks.js"></script>` and angular files in the footer.

I declare my app with `angular.module('myApp', [myServices])` and myApp is the name of my application `<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ApplicationController">`.

I tried to use Turbolinks without AngularJS in my project and it's working but when I added AngularJS, this warning appears `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.`.

How can I use Turbolinks and AngularJS in the same project?

Comment: Seems like you are using competing frameworks. Why do you need both?

Comment: My website already used AngularJS for dynamic content and I just need to add Turbolinks to increase the speed of my pages.

Answer (score 0):

There's a discussion of a workaround on this page to have turbolinks not interact with a div or it's contents. I'm guessing you could apply the same logic to your angularjs app container.

https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/155

In their case, they wrapped the content in a `div` with `id="container"`, then some javascript to handle it.

HTML:

```
<div id="permanent">...stuff...</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:click',function (){
  def turbolink_permanent(id, &block)
    anchor = content_tag(:div, "permanent #{id}", "data-turbolinks-permanent": true, id: id)
    return anchor if request.env["HTTP_TURBOLINKS_REFERRER"]
    html = capture(&block)
    anchor << javascript_tag("document.getElementById('#{id}').innerHTML = #{html.inspect};")
  end
}
```

Comment: But I'm working with plain HTML and it seems to work with erb helper, no?

Comment: I believe that code is what the ERB helper spits out.  Sorry I'm no longer using turbolinks in my project but it seemed like a similar issue to yours.

Answer (score 0):

> I call turbolinks.js in the Head tag  and angular files in the footer.

To prevent Angular JS from loading twice, you will need to include your Angular files in the `<head>` (not just turbolinks.js).

When a page is loaded via Turbolinks, it evaluates script tags in the body, so if your Angular files are included in the footer on various pages, it will load them more than once.